# Does Avaya have an API for retrieving the audio stream of a VoIP call?

Tags: voip, telephony, avaya

I have been up and down the documentation and all over the web looking for an answer to this question but have not had any luck.  I have a project where I am looking to retrieve the live audio stream from an Avaya telephone call and then transcribe the call as its happening.

Does Avaya support this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [DMCC](http://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/dmcc/overview/index.gsp) (which has bindings to different languages and also a language-agnostic XML interface), which implements CSTA ECMA-269 industrial standard. It has several methods to start an API session (`StartApplicationSession`), subscribe to events (`MonitorStart`) and assume *first-party* control over a device (`RegisterTerminal`). If a device is registered by an application in client-media mode, you may directly access the RTP media stream coming into and going out from the phone. RTP address, port and codec are contained in `MediaStartEvent` responses which you can receive via DMCC once you've set the event subscription properly. There's also a distinctive `RecordMessage` method that writes the audio stream from a device to a file (which you may process later).

Registering a device will likely consume a «DMCC license» (one for each registered device). If you use *third-party* call control methods (such as `MakeCall` or `AnswerCall`), a «Basic TSAPI license» will also be consumed for every controlled device. I've discovered out that a «Basic TSAPI» license is consumed as soon as you issue a `MonitorStart` request to subscribe to events. You may want to consult your vendor about how to obtain the appropriate amount of licenses for your AES. I personally found Avaya licenses rather complicated in terms of understanding what license set exactly your application may need. There's [my thread](http://www.devconnectprogram.com/forums/posts/list/17618.page) on Avaya's DevConnect resource which may shed some light here.

Playing with your Avaya AES installation using the [DMCC Dashboard](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/dmcc/development_tools_configurations/dmcc_dashboard/index.gsp) is a good way to familiarize yourself with DMCC API.